# User authentication in oauth2 with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have implemented OAuth 2.0 with spring boot. I am storing the hashed password (including a salt) into my database.

I'm new to Spring and can't figure out how could I authenticate a username/password.

This is my UserDAO class:

```
@Service
public class UserDAO implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private LoginDetailsManager loginDetailsManager;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Get user");
    LoginDetails user = loginDetailsManager.getByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    if (user == null) {
        // Not found...
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "User " + username + " not found.");
    }

    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

    String password = user.getPasswordHash();
    String salt = user.getSalt();
    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPasswordHash(),
            salt,
            grantedAuthorities);
}
}
```

And this is the security configurer from the Application class:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}
```

Questions:

1. How to retrieve the password entered by the user? The implementation of UserDetailsService gives me the username entered by the user.
2. Is there an in-built method to handle this "hashed password+salt" authentication? Am I getting it all wrong?

Comment: I get it. But what about the salt? Don't I need to pass the salt from the database to spring..? The database is currently manually populated. Also, how does spring know which hashing algorithm am I using?

Comment: You can define `saltSource` or implement own `passwordEncoder`

Comment: @Downvoter, please put a comment on improvement!

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving the principal, providing a salt and encoding respectively matching the password are all decoupled from each other in Spring Security. Your UserDetails service is basically a correct way of fetching the principal.

You have to provide a PasswordEncoder, the default in Spring Boot is BCrypt, which doesn't match your hash. The old password encoder (ShaPasswordEncoder and such) as well as the salt sources are no longer picked up by Spring Boot and Spring Security. You have to define them manually.

This configuration should basically do what you want, given you have a `UserDetails` that contains a salt column. If you don't know how to do that, here's the complete implementation [ShaPasswordEncoderConfig.java](https://github.com/springbootbuch/security/blob/master/src/main/java/de/springbootbuch/security/ShaPasswordEncoderConfig.java) from my upcoming book.

```
@Configuration
public class ShaPasswordEncoderConfig 
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public ShaPasswordEncoderConfig(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth
    ) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
            = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(
            userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(
            new ShaPasswordEncoder(256));
        authProvider.setSaltSource(
            user -> ((UserWithSalt)user).getSalt());

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

To make this work, you have to role your own UserDetails implementation and not use that one from Spring Security itself, since it has no attribute to store the salt.

The `SaltSource` I used in the example is a lambda that that casts a `UserDetails` to my implementation and grabs the salt. You can also use  `ReflectionSaltSource` which is one implementation that gets the salt via reflection.

**Edit**

`UserDetails` is easy to implement, see:

You could use an implementation like this:

```
class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final String hashedPassword;
    private final String salt;
    private final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;

    public UserDetailsImpl(String username, String hashedPassword, String salt, List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities) {
        this.username = username;
        this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
        this.salt = salt;
        this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return hashedPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return salt;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt. I just made an interface `UserDetails` which has `getSalt()` method. Where do I use it? Should I make another class "User" to implement that interface and return an instance of "User" from UserDAO?
Very confused.

Comment: No. You extend `UserDetails` and add your salt attribute, together with getter and setter. Can name the attribute anything u want. That name is the name u configure above. You don't call that method / access the attribute directly, Spring does that for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still not clear. How will Spring know the value of salt? How does it get it from the database? Does it pickup from the db automatically?

Also, after extending spring's `UserDetails` by my own UserDetails, I'm unable to return the `User` object from my `UserDAO` class. Because `User` implements spring's UserDetails not mine.

Comment: Okay. Now I have everything. security configurer is enabled in the application class. Beans from the SecurityConfig class are there. UserDetails containing an attribute for salt is implemented. Still getting a bad credentials response. Seems the salt is not getting picked up. Anyways, thanks for bearing this far.

Comment: You're welcome :) Best guess: the hash is compared cased sensitive. I don't know wether the encoder encodes it hex, uppercase or whatever. Anyway must be the same format you stored.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own `PasswordEncoder` interface and using a local static variable to pass it the salt through db.

The implementation is experimental, based on my observation of flow of control:

1. client-secret validation in the PasswordEncoder
2. If step-1 cleared, `loadUserByUsername` in userDAO.
3. Password validation in PasswordEncoder

---

```
public class PasswordEncoderImpl implements PasswordEncoder {

    public static Constants constants = new Constants();

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String salt = constants.getSalt();

    /**
     * If salt is null, it means the value in constants object is empty now.
     * => client-secret validation is going on
     * => we just need the comparision of plain-text string.
     */
        if(salt != null) {
//    case of password authentication
            return DigestUtils.sha256Hex(salt + rawPassword).equalsIgnoreCase(encodedPassword);
        } else {
        //case of client-secret authentication
            return rawPassword.equals(encodedPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

In my UserDAO, where I get the user-details from the persistence, I would store salt into the object constants before return the user:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Get user");
    user = loginDetailsManager.getByUsername(username);
    System.out.println(user.toString());
    if (user == null) {
        // Not found...
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "User " + username + " not found.");
    }

    GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

    constants.set(user.getSalt());

    return new User(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPasswordHash(),
            true, true, true, true,
            grantedAuthorities);
}
```

Comment: Really? A global static object for user specific state? Please do yourself and your users a favor, have a look again at my answer and the docs.

Comment: Yes, that was a horrible mistake. using threadlocal now to pass the salt.

Comment: I fixed my answer. Indeed, the old encoders and salt sources are no longer picked up automatically. I really recommend not using the salt like you propose.